# How to set reorder control at top of the row when tableview is in edit mode in swift 3+

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I want to change and set reorder control icon at top of the row in tableviewcell when tableview is in editmode.

Answer (score 0):

After long try and hit I found this below solution.

for view in cell.subviews {
                if String(describing: view.description).range(of:"Reorder") != nil {

```
                for subview in view.subviews {
                    if subview.isKind(of: UIImageView.self)  {

                        let subImgV = subview as! UIImageView
                        if subImgV.image != UIImage(named: "rearrangeIcon") {
                            subImgV.image = UIImage(named: "rearrangeIcon")
                            subview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height); // First we need to increse its size as it is superview after that set imageView content mode left, right, top, bottom
                            subImgV.contentMode = .top

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```